# Is mixed collation in a database a problem?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database where some tables are Collation `utf8_general_ci` and some tables are Collation `utf8_bin`. Is this an issue that will cause unexpected behavior, or is it just a matter of performance?

Comment: MySQL Documentation should cover this shouldn't it?

Comment: I think it would hurt joins but don't know for sure